# How to blur text in a video using windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, video-editing

If I have screen recording videos containing text that I want to blur or censor out, how can I do that in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that it is *not possible* to blur footage with the default set of Windows 7 apps. 'Windows Movie Maker' used to be the go to free software for basic editing but it's now only downloadable from Microsoft and isn't actually 'free' for all intensive purposes.

Your solution is here:

Download 'Shotcut' video editor for free [here](https://www.shotcut.org/).

Follow the instructional video on how to blur parts of an image using Shotcut [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQ5sfaGCm1w)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter, that you are running Windows 7.

#### What you need is a video editing program.

For blurring, pixellation and basic censoring, you do not necessarily need expensive software such as Sony Vegas.

Free software such as OpenShot (originally for Linux, but also available for Windows) could also do your job.
Alternatviely, you can download and burn a DVD with [Ubuntu Studio,](https://ubuntustudio.org/download/) and boot from that DVD. **Some video editing software, including *KDEnlive* is pre-installed out of the box.**